# C# Adding multiple items to list

Tags: c#, list

Recently picked up C# from a python background. Currently experimenting with lists in C#. Lets say I designed an application that I wanted to store all the information about a car e.g. the name, make and colour. I also want it so that the user can add multiple cars to the list so they can be displayed later? How would I go about this task?

```
         private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Cars = new List <string>();

        string colour = txtInput.Text;

        Cars.Add(colour);

        lstDisplay.Items.Add(colour);

    }
}
```

}

Here is some code I have so far. The program takes input from the user and stores it, then adds it to the list and displays it to a list box. However I notice each time I add a new colour to the list it seems to always be empty?
How would I make it so that the list will hold the input of different colours?

Comment: The generic class List<T> has a method called AddRange where you can add more than one item in a single call. Of course you could always have a loop over your car data and add item by item with Add. But your question is too broad. Do you have a Car class? Where do you get the data to initialize a single Car instance? In other words, you should show what have you tried.

Comment: You'd create a `Car` class with all the relevant information, then create a `List<Car>`. At this stage I'd recommend getting hold of a good book or C# tutorial that can teach you all the most important aspects of C# in an ordered, structured and consistent way. While Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, it's not a good way to learn the building blocks of a language.

Comment: the key words you can do some research on would be GenericList. It also depends what you want to be able to do on a list.  if not much then an `Array` might be ok.  `IEnumerable`, `IList`, ...the list goes on (pun intended) :-)

Comment: Added updates of my code

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading you correctly, every time the button is clicked, you want to add a new color to the list, am I correct?

If that is the case, your problem is right here:

```
List<string> Cars = new List <string>();
```

You are recreating the list every time you press the button, essentially zeroing out the list.  `List<type> name = new List<type>();` creates a brand new list, even if it is called more than once.  Therefore, when you call it in the method, you are doing just that.

Instead, you want to put that outside of the method, in the beginning of the class, so it is only created once.  Something like:

```
class CarClass()
{
  List<string> Cars = new List <string>();

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    string colour = txtInput.Text;
    Cars.Add(colour);
    lstDisplay.Items.Add(colour);
  }
}
```

This way, the list is created and initialized at the start of the class creation. Your method will then add to the list without zeroing it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already have some cars when you are creating this list, you can do:

```
var list = new List<Car>(existingCars);
```

if not, then later do something like:

```
list.AddRange(existingCars);
list.Add(existingCar);
```

---

**Edit:**
each time you are creating new list, so move this line

```
List<string> Cars = new List <string>();
```

from this method to class, like:

```
private readonly List<string> Cars = new List <string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

To better answer your question I need a little more information. You can store the car information in memory but when the application is restarted all saved car information will be lost. If you need to keep track of the car information for an indefinite amount of time then you need to store the car information in something like a database.

```
class CarClass {

    private List<string> Cars;

    public CarClass() {
        Cars = new List <string>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string colour = txtInput.Text;

        Cars.Add(colour);

        lstDisplay.Items.Add(colour);

    }

}
```

This would only store the Cars list in memory when the CarClass is instantiated and used. If you need it for later, when the CarClass is no longer referenced, you would need to save the carlist information in a database.